# Polymer fix messing up Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, polymer

I'm new to Polymer and as far as I've read about it, it isn't compatible with Mozilla and Safari or it has issues. I've read in StackOverflow that adding

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
});
```

would help the browsers cope up with the code. Now, I've tried it on my code it works. The content is displaying properly in Mozilla, however, it messes up the Javascript that I wrote along with Polymer. I tried two options, the first one

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    Polymer({
      is: "main-header"
    }); });
```

I did this and there are still error logs on the console while if I wrap the whole script, it wouldn't work as well. Example:

```
 addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    Polymer({
      is: "main-header"
    }); 
    // extra code here
 });
```

I think wrapping addEventListener to the whole code is also causing the problem. Any ideas how to fix or are there any other viable options than adding an event listener to the code?

Comment: Have you included the webcomponents.js

Comment: Yes. I use webcomponents-lite.js since I'm using Polymer 1.0

Comment: Can you show your console errors?

Comment: It's more on error 500 since the data is null because the forms don't pass any data to the back-end. If there are no errors, the display and functions used in the javascript doesn't work or isn't displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
});
```

is messing up my Javascript because it has a conflict with

```
addEventListener('HTMLImportsReady', function() {
});
```

I had to remove it in order for the script to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Polymer-CLI

It comes with some polyfills out of the box.
I'm not sure whitch ones but it does include the one your inquiring about.

> https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli